# potential energy change in conservative field

Tags: potential-energy

Is it true that potential energy of a particle always decreases in the direction of conservative force acting on it?

Answer (score 1):

Conservative forces are associated with potential energies, the relation between them is given by: 
[image]

F is the conservative force, U is the potential energy. That equation says that the conservative force acts in a direction of decreasing potential energy. So if a particle only experiences the force associated with the potential energy, it is true. It will move in the direction of decreasing potential energy

Comment: ok take a inverse square force like **A/r^2** always pointing towards origin. where 'A' is some constant and 'r' is distance from origin of force. then potential energy function for this is **U= A/r + c** . where c is arbitrary constant. then potential in this case increases in direction of force.

Comment: The force toward origin should be **(A/r^2)*(-R)** R capital being the unit vector in r direction. The potential energy is MINUS the integration of F which is **U= -A/r+c**. There are two minuses, one from the force and one from the relation above, so the function you integrate is positive, the result of the integral is negative. So at r=0 the potential is minus infinity while at infinity it is 0. Is it clear?